# append a csv row at a list

Tags: python, pandas

I need to append a specific column of CSV file into a list.

I write the following code but the length of the list is 1!

It seems like it write all the rows as one element at the list.

```
true = []
X = pd.read_csv('DataSet.txt',encoding='utf-8',quotechar="'")
true.append(X['T'])
```

T: The name  of the column at `DataSet.txt` file.

Comment: That's going to be a `pd.Series` object. You can access the values in that series with: `X['T'].values`. If that `np.array` isn't what you want, you can do: `X['T'].values.tolist()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
X = pd.read_csv('DataSet.txt',encoding='utf-8',quotechar="'")
true = X["T"].values.tolist()
```

Or, if you wanna append to an existing list:

```
true = []
X = pd.read_csv('DataSet.txt',encoding='utf-8',quotechar="'")
true.extend(X["T"].values.tolist())
```